# Interpretation of interaction in fixed effects model

Tags: interaction, panel-data

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to interpret the interaction term in fixed effect model.

Apparently, the Mo1 increases the positive relationship between IV and DV.
The Mo2 decreases the positive relationship between IV and DV.

I want to ask two questions.
1)
Besides this, how can I interpret the results?
2)
If one unit of IV is increased, what will happen?

IV = independent variable, DV = dependent variable, Mo = moderator.
SE is within a parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

When involved in an interaction it doesn't makes sense to think about a change in a variable in isolation, because it's "effect" depends on the value of the variable it is interacted with. This is as exactly why we fit an interaction in the first place.

Comment: So, unless I draw an interaction graph, that is all that I can say about the results?

Comment: you don't need to draw an interaction graph, but it can help!

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not, please let us know why. Also, if you haven't already, please consider upvoting it.